# bookmarklet to add a parameter to the url and resubmit it?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Is the following possible with a bookmarklet?

1. Add an additional parameter to the URL (include_docs=true)
2. Re-submit the URL

I have this but it fails silently on firefox.  I haven't tried it with another browser:

```
javascript:(

   function()
   {
      key = encodeURI('include_docs'); value = encodeURI('true');

      var kvp = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');

      var i=kvp.length; var x; while(i--) 
      {
        x = kvp[i].split('=');

        if (x[0]==key)
        {
            x[1] = value;
            kvp[i] = x.join('=');
            break;
        }
      }
      if(i<0) {kvp[kvp.length] = [key,value].join('=');}

      //this will reload the page, it's likely better to store this until finished
      document.location.search = kvp.join('&'); 
  }()
);
```

Comment: `document.location += '&include_docs=true'` ?

Comment: Thanks that worked: `javascript:(function(){document.location+='&include_docs=true'}())`.  If you add it as an answer I can credit you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to over-complicate anything ;-)

```
document.location += '&include_docs=true';
```

That should do the trick. In bookmarklet form:

```
javascript:(function(){document.location+='&include_docs=true'}());
```

Comment: some browsers won't recognize `location` as a `document` property ... better to use `window`

Comment: @charlietfl: What browsers? `document.location` seems to be supported [on all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location#Browser_compatibility)